# What does the "ve" in "execve" mean?

Tags: posix

What does the `ve` in `execve` mean?

I read through `man execve` but didn't see what it means. I gather it might be "vector" but not sure. What does the `ve` mean?

Comment: C loves to save memory like this. [creat](https://linux.die.net/man/2/creat) is famous for that. Sometimes trimming down names to save a few characters takes it [too far](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10893/what-did-ken-thompson-mean-when-he-said-id-spell-creat-with-an-e), though. There's not even any orthogonality in how they trim down names... for example, [fprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf) stands for "file print formatted".

Answer (score 22):

`execve()` is a POSIX (and UNIX systems in general) function of the family of the `exec*()` functions that replace the current process image.

The `v` comes from the fact that it takes an argument `argv` to the vector of arguments to the program (the same way the `main` function of a C program may take it).

The `e` comes from another of its arguments, `envp`, which is similarly a vector of the environment variables (key/value pairs like `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`).

For more information, see for instance the [Open Group's docs on `exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html).

Comment: From the link - `int execve(const char *path, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);`

Answer (score 6):

From [Wikipedia we can see that:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(system_call)#C_language_prototypes)

> Some implementations provide these functions named with a leading underscore (e.g. _execl).
>
> The base of each is exec (execute), followed by one or more letters:
>
> e – An array of pointers to environment variables is explicitly passed to the >new process image.
>
> l – Command-line arguments are passed individually (a list) to the function.
>
> p – Uses the PATH environment variable to find the file named in the file >argument to be executed.
>
> **v – Command-line arguments are passed to the function as an array (vector) of pointers.**
>
> In the execl, execlp, execv, and execvp calls, the new process image inherits the current environment variables.
>   *(Emphasis mine.)*

So your suspicions are correct.

Comment: Also stated in Stevens' "Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment"

Comment: Good to know. Thank you.